# Unable to access company tenant in AzureAD with correct settings

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have a paid account in AzureAD. 
using Xamarin forms with below code:
I was able to display the Sign-In Page and able to enter the my email address.

**PROBLEM** :
when I click the next button after adding email addr, I was taken to this Page: taking you to your organization's sign in page BUT the activity indicator kept in infinite loop...... nothing being returned.

Update

I tested on 2 Droid phones. 
A_phone with Android version 8.0 , this work shortly. Later I deleted it in phone and redeploy from VS2017 to phone to ensure working. But after redeployed, it is not working now.  Now B_phone with Android ver 4.3, this show WebPage not available. Why B_Phone not working??

Why this is happening?

```
public static string ApplicationID = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx";
public static string tenanturl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx";
public static string ReturnUri = "http://appname";

public static string GraphResourceUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
public static AuthenticationResult AuthenticationResult = null;



private async void Login_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    try
    {
         var data = await DependencyService.Get<IAuthenticator>()
                      .Authenticate(App.tenanturl, App.GraphResourceUri, App.ApplicationID, App.ReturnUri);

         if (data != null)
         {
            App.AuthenticationResult = data;
            NavigateTopage(data);
          }

    }
  catch(Exception)
  { }
 }




 class Authenticator : IAuthenticator
    {
        public async Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string tenantUrl, string graphResourceUri, string ApplicationID, string returnUri)
        {
            try
            {
                var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(tenantUrl);

                if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Any())


                authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().FirstOrDefault().Authority);

                var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceUri, ApplicationID, new Uri(returnUri), new PlatformParameters((Activity)Forms.Context));

                return authResult;
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
```

Please help. Your help is important to me.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any exception?

Comment: No Exception ... the activity indicator just kept looping.. no result returned. Are above settings correct? Why this happening? How to troubleshoot this case?

Comment: If you are looping, probable there's an error in authentication. Set a breakpoint in your  catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            } and see what ex has.

Comment: now I am getting Web page not available.  What I need to do? Does Chrome Browser version matter in this authentication? Does Droid API level matter?

Comment: Do you have your credentials all correctly setup? And permissions in Azure AD?

Comment: I tested on 2 Droid phones.  A_phone with Android version 8.0 , this work now. Now B_phone with Android ver 4.3, this show WebPage not available. Why B_Phone not working?? It should be the same for all Droid phone right?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your Reply URL is your main homepage URL and your Redirect URI in your config matches what's in your app registration. Also verify that the Client ID in the config matches the App ID in your application. You can add an else statement to ensure that you navigate somewhere even if the user is not authenticated.